# Binding extension content scripts to Chrome's start page?

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extension, content-script

Is there any way to bind a content script to Chrome's start page?

I tried setting `matches` to `"*"`, but it doesn't even run. With `"*://*/*"` it does not bind.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, you cannot*. Technically, the start page is `chrome://newtab/`, and Chrome Extensions cannot access `chrome://` pages for security reasons, not even with the widest `"<all_urls>"` permission.

Your only hope is to [make your own New Tab page](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/override), though it would be hard to replicate all of the default functionality (e.g. thumbnails of top sites).

---

* One can enable this with Chrome Flags: `chrome://flags/#extensions-on-chrome-urls` But this is only applicable if the extension is for personal use and is a potential security risk.

Answer (score 0):

Yes!  Chrome's Start page (¿now?) has the hidden URL of the form:

```
https://www.google.com/_/chrome/newtab?espv=2&ie=UTF-8
```

And extensions with `manifest.json`s like:

```js
{
    "manifest_version": 2,
    "content_scripts": [ {
        "js":               [ "HelloWorld.js" ],
        "matches":          [ "*://*/_/chrome/newtab*" ]
    } ],
    "name":         "Chrome start test",
    "description":  "Runs on the Chrome Start page",
    "version":      "1"
}
```

...run perfectly well on the Start page.

Comment: It does not work.